# ORDER BY with priority

Tags: mysql

I want to use ORDER BY on uniqueid with priority.
My table looks like this :

```
+-------------+------------------+
| disposition |     uniqueid     |  
+-------------+------------------+
| ANSWERED    | 1595409523.22546 |  
| NO ANSWER   | 1595409523.22546 |  
| BUSY        | 1595409523.22546 | 
| BUSY        | 1595406475.22391 |  
| NO ANSWER   | 1595406475.22391 |  
| BUSY        | 1595406475.22391 |  
+-------------+------------------+
```

I want for example on the ID: 1595409523.22546 to appear that the line where there is 'ANSWER', if there is no 'ANSWER' I want that 'NO ANSWER' is displayed otherwise BUSY etc ...
The result should be :

```
+-------------+------------------+--+
| disposition |     uniqueid     |  |
+-------------+------------------+--+
| ANSWERED    | 1595409523.22546 |  |
| NO ANSWER   | 1595406475.22391 |  |
|             |                  |  |
+-------------+------------------+--+
```

Could you help me ? Thank you !

Comment: You don't appear to have a way of identifying the most recent disposition.(which is what I'm guessing you want).

Comment: Not the most recent. I want this in specific order. First see if there is 'ANSWER' then 'NO ANSWER' then 'BUSY' ect... If for example there is ANSWER, then, only the line where there is ANSWER has to appear.

Comment: you should create a table with your possible dispositions and their priority

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your MySql version is 8.0+ and supports window functions then you can use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
select t.disposition, t.uniqueid
from (
  select *,
    row_number() over (partition by uniqueid 
                       order by field(disposition, 'ANSWERED', 'NO ANSWER', 'BUSY')) rn
  from tablename                                    
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

For earlier versions you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select case 1
         when max(disposition = 'ANSWERED') then 'ANSWERED'
         when max(disposition = 'NO ANSWER') then 'NO ANSWER'
         when max(disposition = 'BUSY') then 'BUSY' 
       end disposition,
       uniqueid  
from tablename
group by uniqueid
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3c6a485001b6ae72ffc4d25e014a31b9).
Results:

```
> disposition |         uniqueid
> :---------- | ---------------:
> ANSWERED    | 1595409523.22546
> NO ANSWER   | 1595406475.22391
```

Answer (score 2):

To check, for each uniqueid, a ranked list of dispositions and return the lowest ranked one found, or the lexically least disposition if none from the ranked list is found:

```
select
    if(min(find_in_set(disposition, 'ANSWERED,NO ANSWER,BUSY')),elt(min(find_in_set(disposition, 'ANSWERED,NO ANSWER,BUSY')),'ANSWERED,NO ANSWER,BUSY'),min(disposition)) disposition,
    uniqueid
from yourtable
group by uniqueid
```

Comment: Updating per your comment.  But "etc" isn't good enough; if you want each possible disposition to have a priority, you need to specify them all in order

Comment: Did you leave off the group by?  Updated my answer

Comment: It works too, thanks ! But how could I do if I want to add another value in the disposition field ?

Comment: Add it to the list (in all three places), in whatever order you want